# The method call of Observable.OnSubscribe interface and its full description

Tags: rx-java

I explore different ways to create new Observabe in RxJava.
Unfortunately my attempts to find full description of method

[call()](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/functions/Action1.html#call-T-) ( `interface Observable.OnSubscribe<T>` ) have failed.

Please can anybody help me to find out what does that method do or to share some detailed information about this method.

Thank you very much!

Comment: It is part of RxJava 1 which is no longer supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RxJava provides several factory methods, which are accessible through Observable class:

Lets have a look at an eager implementation: Observable.just()
You may also use: Observable.fromCallable(() -> { return  }) or Observable.defer(() -> { return > } in order to defer a expensive calculation (lazy). There are also Observable.fromArray / Observable.fromIterable, which will take a list of objects eagerly and emit them, when subscribed to. There is also an interop for Java-Futures: Observable.fromFuture. Also there is Observable.create, which can be used to emit dedicated contract-events like onNext/onComplete/onError. Furthermore you can use Observable.create in order to transform a callback-style Api to RxJava-Observables.

The mentioned interface Action1 is a functional interface like Consumer from Java8. It is not a tool for creating Observables, instead it is used to inject custom code into the Observable.

Lets have a look at this Example:

```
Observable<String> obs$ = Observable.fromCallable(() -> "Test");
obs$.subscribe(s -> System.out.println(s));
```

In this example you "could" pass in a Action1 to subscribe, in order to get invoked, when a value is emitted. As with RxJava2, there is no Action1 anymore. Instead one would use a Consumer.